# How to use a struct defined in a Thrift file using keyword "include"

Tags: java, communication, thrift

I'm a newbie with Thrift. I have the following question:
Suppose that I defined a struct in file "Ex1.thrift" as follow:

```
namespace java tut1
struct Address {
 1:string nameStreet,
 2:i32 idHouse
}
```

I want to use struct Address in file "Ex2.thrift", how could I do that? 
I tried this way but Thrift compiler doesn't work:

```
include "Ex1.thrift"
namespace java tut2
struct Student {
 1:string name,
 2:i32 age,
 3:Address add
}

service ExampleService {
 list<Student> getListStudent()
}
```

Thank you so much for any answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to provide Ex1 prefix while using address in Ex2.thrift

```
    include "Ex1.thrift"
    namespace java tut2
    struct Student {
    1:string name,
    2:i32 age,
    3:Ex1.Address add
    }

    service ExampleService {
    list<Student> getListStudent()
    }
```

This works in Thrift 0.8.0